# (Flappy Bird) Function to alter object that spawns based on number of already instantiated prefabs?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, flappy-bird-clone

In my flappy bird game, I want to create a loop that works through instantiated pipes, altering the pipe prefab (to reduce space between pipes + increase respawn rate) to increase difficulty based on player score.

The code below works, but I'd like to implement difficulty differently. I don't know how to add newly instantiated objects to a list.

I'd also like to add an event animation that plays after each level (before new pipe prefab instantiated), pausing the loop as the "new level" text flies across the screen.

```
    private void Start()
    {
        InvokeRepeating("SpawnPipe", .05f, respawnRate);
    }
  
private void SpawnPipe()
    {
        int levelOne = 8;
        int levelTwo = 18;
        int levelThree = 29;


        if(GameManager.score < levelOne)
        {
            GameObject pipes1 = Instantiate(pipePrefab1, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            pipes1.transform.position += Vector3.up * Random.Range(minHeight, maxHeight);
        }

        if (GameManager.score > levelOne && GameManager.score < levelTwo)
        {
            GameObject pipes2 = Instantiate(pipePrefab2, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            pipes2.transform.position += Vector3.up * Random.Range(minHeight, maxHeight);
        }

        if (GameManager.score > levelTwo && GameManager.score < levelThree)
        {
            GameObject pipes3 = Instantiate(pipePrefab3, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            pipes3.transform.position += Vector3.up * Random.Range(minHeight, maxHeight);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are asking for but Lists are used like this:

```
List<GameObject> pipes = new List<>();
pipes.add(pipes1);
```

Using InvokeRepeating to spawn the pipes is probably a bad idea because it gives you little control. I would recommend to check in your Update loop if a certain time passed or distance was traveled and spawn pipes accordingly;